# What is this Californian shrub?

Tags: species-identification, botany

I spotted this shrub-like plant in California, USA.

[image]

Comment: found it in Los Angeles

Comment: I'm sure it's listed somewhere within [this](http://calscape.org/loc-California/) database. I'm currently categorizing the leaves as: elliptic in shape, pinnate in venation, entire margins. Anyone agree?

Comment: @Charles A randomly chosen plant from So. Cal. could be from anywhere given the climate and horticultural practices, so I don't think I'd limit the search to natives.

Comment: It may be useful to add a clearer picture of the flowers.

Comment: unfortunately i don.t have another picture of it..

Answer (score 1):

Almost definitely not a CA native.

It looks like a coleus to me -- cultivars are pretty diverse but typically have variegated leaves with some amount of purple coloration.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plectranthus_scutellarioides

Comment: Flowers look very different though...

Comment: Not a _Coleus_. They have square stems and opposing leaves.

Answer (score -1):

It is Bouganvillia. If you have pets you don't want one even if your neighbors have pets. When the flowers drop they get all over the place and if they get into any food or water source for pets they will slowly die from the Poisonous oils that seep out of the flower. Other than that they are a very easy vine to grow and easy to train.

Comment: Flowers don't resemble bougainvilla. And leaves don't either as matter of fact.

Comment: I know bougainvilla and that wasn.t it.